# Do I need to have a multicolumn index?

Tags: mysql

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * 
FROM (
`phppos_items`
)
WHERE (
name LIKE  'AB10LA2%'
OR item_number LIKE  'AB10LA2%'
OR category LIKE  'AB10LA2%'
)
AND deleted =0
ORDER BY  `name` ASC 
LIMIT 16

+----+-------------+--------------+-------+-----------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys                     | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+-----------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | phppos_items | index | item_number,name,category,deleted | name | 257     | NULL |   32 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+-----------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

This query takes 9 seconds to run (the table has 1 million + rows).

I have an index on item_number,name,category,deleted separately. How can I speed up this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best I'm aware, MySQL doesn't know how to perform bitmap OR index scans. But you could rewrite it as the union of three queries to force it to do such a thing, if you've an index on each field. If so, this will be very fast:

```
select *
from (
  select * from (
           select *
           from phppos_items
           where name like 'AB10LA2%' and deleted = 0
           order by `name` limit 16
           ) t
  union
  select * from (
           select *
           from phppos_items
           where item_number like 'AB10LA2%' and deleted = 0
           order by `name` limit 16
           ) t
  union
  select * from (
           select *
           from phppos_items
           where category like 'AB10LA2%' and deleted = 0
           order by `name` limit 16
           ) t
  ) as top rows
order by `name` limit 16
```

Comment: Nice... Well, it should be checked ordering this huge table three times is actually a good idea... Might work, though...

Comment: If MySQL does this right, it'll top-n sort each subset before applying the union. Your suggestion, by contrast, would require ordering each of the subsets entirely over each field (since the `union` clause will need to strip uniques). In other words, ordering occurs either way; this version would make it fetch top-n rows before ordering.

Comment: You may be right. This is probably the best solution in general. It's a very nice idea, +1

Comment: Could you explain where there a double select? Why does the union need a select * from (select * from phppos_items...ect). Why can't it be just select * from phppos_items?

Comment: Postgres will only accept one order by/limit clause when you're unioning statements, at the very end of it; this makes the subselects necessary. MySQL might make do without them.

Answer (score 1):

The `OR` operator can be poison for an execution plan. You could try to re-phrase your query replacing the `OR` clauses by an equivalent `UNION`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM `phppos_items`
  WHERE name LIKE 'AB10LA2%'
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM `phppos_items`
  WHERE item_number LIKE 'AB10LA2%'
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM `phppos_items`
  WHERE category LIKE  'AB10LA2%'
)
WHERE deleted =0
ORDER BY  `name` ASC 
LIMIT 16
```

This will allow MySQL to run several sub-queries in parallel before applying the `UNION` operator to each of the subqueries' results. I know this can help a lot with Oracle. Maybe MySQL can do similar things? Note: I assume that `LIKE 'AB10LA2%'` is quite a selective filter. Otherwise, this might not improve things due to late ordering and limiting in the execution plan. See [Denis's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178068/do-i-need-to-have-a-mulicolumn-index/6178162#6178173) answer for a more general approach.

In any case, I think a multi-column index won't help you because you have `'%'` signs in your search expressions. That way, only the first column in the multi-column index could be used, the rest would still need index-scanning or a full table scan.

Comment: I will give this a try, this sounds like a great idea.

Comment: this is correct but it'll lead to fetch all rows and sorting them.

Comment: @Denis: Good point, but I think the `'AB10LA2%'` filter is selective enough to ignore this fact

Comment: @Lukas: you're probably right. :-) @Chris: Seem my own answer in case you also need to deal with less selective filters.

Comment: Will the union produce double results for example if an item has a name and item_number of AB10?

Comment: `UNION` produces only unique results. `UNION ALL` will produce double results (but is faster)